# how to catch an error with typescript using error.response.status

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Me and my team have been stuck on this problem for weeks and now it is affecting the way we handle our errors. We've tried every combination suggested on the internet and nothing seems to work. I've tried `any`, `unknown`, `HttpErrorResponse`, and now `AxiosError`. Nothing seems to work with typescript. Any suggesitons?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So when I tried this solution where I add `useUnknownInCatchVariables: false` inside the tsconfig.json file. This made fixed the issue, but when I tried npm start it would boot up saying that it was not recognized. Once I updated from 3.9.6 to 4.4.4, npm start then worked.

solution:

- replace with `catch(err)`, don't need to specify any type.
- add `useUnknownInCatchVariables: false` to your tsconfig.json file.
- make sure you are at least running version 4.4 for typescript